# My python socket code does not receive or display data from web application(xampp or other)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

i want to create something like `request.get()` function do in python means i want to create a http socket program which send request for a `html` page to web server like `xampp`, iis or other but my code does,t show receive data i am confused is it receive data from web server and if receive show does not it show.
i am also try to convert `unicode('utf-8')` to string but still not working

```
import socket
ip="127.0.0.1"
port=8080
com=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
com.connect((ip,port))
data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)
data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)
data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)
data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)
com.close()
```

this is output.

> Through Server >
>
> Through Server >
>
> Through Server >
>
> Through Server >

It does not show any data i don't why.
is it receiving or not

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

import socket
ip=str(raw_input('Enter IP Adress to connect : '))

port=input('Enter Port to connect: ')

com=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

com.connect((ip,port))

t = "GET /impodocuments/test2.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Host: localhost:80\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

t = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))
t = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n";

com.send(bytes(t))

data = com.recv(9999)

print 'Through Server >' + str(data)

data = com.recv(9999)

print 'Through Server >' + str(data)

data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)

data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)

data = com.recv(9999)
print 'Through Server >' + str(data)

com.close()